# code inside dll

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to see the code inside an asp.net dll. which tool do I need to use. Can I see it using visual studio 2010 ? Someone suggested to use refactor?

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were telling you to use [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1), which was the de facto decompilation utility for years and years. However, it's no longer free-as-in-beer, and Telerik has recently stepped in with [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiling.aspx), so I suggest you give that a go.

Answer (score 2):

[IL Spy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) is my current favourite Reflector replacement.

(RIP Reflector)

Answer (score 1):

That'd be [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/).

There are a few alternatives as well, such as Telerik's new [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiling.aspx). JetBrains is now also [bundling a decompiler with ReSharper 6](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/02/resharper-6-bundles-decompiler-free-standalone-tool-to-follow/) and promising a free standalone decompiler to be released.

Answer (score 0):

you can use reflector tool for that. There are many such tools available, see the below link for more details.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/look-inside-net-dll-files-with-reflector/625